# get user email from Facebook Using FBgraphUser In Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

Im Trying to store the users email address in mt parse database but i cant seem to find the right way of getting this done
my code below

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *result, NSError *error) {


        if (error) {
            // Handle it
        } else {
            PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];
            me[@"facebookId"] = result.objectID;
            me[@"facebookName"] = result.name;
            me[@"facebookProfile"] = result.link;

            [me saveEventually];
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, **result** is an NSDictionary instance, conforming to FBGraphUser protocol. That mean it still can be treated as dictionary, for example you can send `-objectForKey:` message to it. Actually FBGraphUser protocol only adds a "shortcuts" for some objects, stored in the dictionary. So, by calling:

```
NSString *mail = result[@"email"];
```

You will get the email. This is a handy equivalent for:

```
NSString *mail = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
```

For all possible keys for user look [Graph Api Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user).

Comment: but i need to get the email first and it seems FBGraphUser hasn,t got the email in it

Comment: Sorry im still new to all this  i dont understand what you mean by You can use key-value access with result:

Comment: ive add this now but im still getting Null from the email address

Comment: As told in the documentation, `This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available.`

Comment: i thought everyone had an email address in facebook ? even if its the facebook email address

Comment: Yes, but who knows what exactly meant in that documentation. Try to request `email` reading permission. It worked for me.

Comment: ok i will try someon elses facebook account as my security permissions block access to my email